# Passing multiple inputs into a MATLAB function via loop?

Tags: matlab, loops

I have multiple variables var_1, var_2, var_3....var_9 (they are named like that) that I want to pass in a function. All of the variables are saved in the workspace. The function takes 2 variables, and spits out an output. I want to compare var_1 with all the variables, including itself, so I prefer to automate it in a loop.

So I want to execute

function(var_1,var_1)--> display answer, function(var_1,var_2)--> display answer...function(var_1,var_9)-->display answer all at once in a loop. I've tried the following, with no luck:

```
for i=1:7
functionname(var_1,var_'num2str(i)')
end
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: see the official help on this subject: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make a dynamic variable name directly. But you can use the `eval`-function to evaluate an expression as a string. The string can be generated with `sprintf` and replaces `%d` with your value.

```
for i=1:7
  eval(sprintf('functionname(var_1,var_%d)', i));
end
```

**But: Whenever you can, you should avoid using the `eval` function**. A much **better solution** is to use a cell array for this purpose. In the documentation of Matlab there is a [whole article](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) about the why and possible alternatives. To make it short, here is the code that uses a cell array:

```
arr = {val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4, val_5, val_6, val_7, val_8, val_9};

for i = 1:length(arr)
  functionname(arr{1},arr{i})
end
```

Comment: @nkjt: I edited my answer and proposed the better approach.